# How to pass a function name as a parameter for dynamic url?

Tags: django, django-views, dynamic-url

I am trying to pass a function as a parameter to a dynamic URL. This is the code:

```
path('like/<str:view>', like_view, name='like')
```

I then use that view variable to do a reverse with the view function.

```
def like_view(request, view, *args, **kwargs):
    view = view
    post = Article.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('article_id'))
    post.likes += 1
    post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view))

def sac_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Article.objects.filter(committee="2")
    context = {
        "title" : "Student Academic Committee",
        "articles" : queryset,
        "view" : 'sac_view'
    }
    return render(request, 'c.html', context)
```

However, it raises an error that says (not sure how to format it properly sorry):

```
NoReverseMatch at /like/sac_view
Reverse for 'sac_view' not found. 'sac_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/sac_view
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'sac_view' not found. 'sac_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\benja\\Desktop\\mysite\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\benja\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Mon, 04 Jan 2021 04:01:36 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\Desktop\mysite\mysite\blog\views.py, line 80, in like_view
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view)) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py, line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
```

even though sac_view is a view function. Is there a datatype like function? I'm really not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your whole code, not the part _you think_ the error is in. Also post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Much better. I don't understand what are you exactly trying to do, but your `reverse(view)` fails because `view` is equal to `"sac_view"` and you don't have a `path` with `name='sac_view'` in your `urls.py`. Which URL are you expecting it to redirect to?

Comment: I kinda got mixed up with view function and URL names. Sorry about that. I got it working now! Thanks

Comment: To be honest the phrase "view function" is a bit misleading there. I'm glad that it's been resolved.